# biber/biblatex: \DeclareSourcemap conflicting with bcf file?

Tags: biblatex, biber

So I'm trying to get `\DeclareSourcemap` working according to the biblatex manual.
Here's my code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{p.bib}
  @article{A1,
  author={Aa, A and Bb, B},
  title={Title},
  abstract={abs},
  journal={J BS},
  year={1999},
  }
  @conference{A2,
  author={Aa, A and Ab, S},
  title={Title},
  abstract={abs},
  journal={J BS},
  year={2009},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{p.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=title]
      \step[fieldset=title, fieldvalue=Test]
}}}    
\begin{document}
\textcite{A1,A2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Running this through latex/biber doesn't change the `title` field to 'Test'.
In the `.bcf` file, the sourcemap rules are created, here is a relevant snippet:

```
<!-- SOURCEMAP -->
<bcf:sourcemap>
  <bcf:maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
    <bcf:map>
      <bcf:map_step map_field_source="title"/>
      <bcf:map_step map_field_set="title" map_field_value="Test"/>
    </bcf:map>
  </bcf:maps>
  <bcf:maps datatype="bibtex" driver_defaults="1">
    <bcf:map>
      <bcf:map_step map_type_source="conference" map_type_target="inproceedings"/>
      <bcf:map_step map_type_source="electronic" map_type_target="online"/>
      <bcf:map_step map_type_source="www" map_type_target="online"/>
  […]
```

It seems my additional block does not get processed because there is another `maps` block for `bibtex` (And this does get processed, as it changes `@conference` to `@inproceedings`)?
If I copy the `map` block into `biber.conf`, it works as expected.
So here is my question: How do I use `\DeclareSourcemap` correctly ensuring that the map gets executed, independent of possible other blocks?

Comment: Strange, your example works for me and changes the titles as expected. You don't need the `\step[fieldsource=title]` line by the way, it isn't doing anything in your example.

Comment: Since the example works and the problem was not updated, the question will be closed as too localized. It can be reopened if further information would be provided in the question.