# Handling interference between biber.conf and \DeclareSourcemap of biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber

In the MWE below, I show that I have a bibliographic entry, which has had comment characters `%` embedded in the `abstract` field; while this passes with `bibtex`, with `biblatex`/`biber` it makes a problem, since biber will compact all lines of the field into a single line in the `.bbl` file. So I use a `biber.conf` file to completely avoid having the `abstract` field entered in the `.bbl` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  bibencoding=utf8,
  backend=biber,
  natbib,
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true,
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{trace}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article {jo-audm08,
  author = {Some Author},
  title = {{Testing the title of a paper}},
  url = {http://example.com/paper.pdf},
  journal={Proceedings of Some Conference},
  pages={123--127},
  publisher = {example.com},
  year={2008},
  mycustomfield = {whatever},
  lastaccessed = {Last Accessed: 13 April, 2009},
  lastmodified = {Last Modified: 10/28/2008 14:46:42},
  abstract = {%
In this paper, we would like to describe the employment of  .. %
  },
}
\end{filecontents*}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-possible-to-suppress-a-specific-field-from-bibtex-bbl-in-biblatex/33309#33309
\begin{filecontents*}{biber.conf}
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_set="ABSTRACT" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newif\ifDoingSourcemap
\DoingSourcemapfalse
% \DoingSourcemaptrue % uncomment this

\ifDoingSourcemap
  \DeclareSourcemap{
      \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
          \step[fieldsource=mycustomfield]
          \step[fieldset=usera,origfieldval]
      }
    }
  }
  \DeclareFieldFormat{usera}{#1} % not mycustomfield
\fi

\begin{document}

Citing here: \cite{jo-audm08}

\printbibliography[sorting=none]

\end{document}
```

This MWE compiles fine with `pdflatex test.tex && biber test && pdflatex test.tex && pdflatex test.tex`.

Now, I want to use a custom field `mycustomfield` in my bibliographic entry, and for its handling, I've set up a `\DeclareSourcemap` which maps `mycustomfield` to `usera` of `biblatex`. So, I uncomment the `\DoingSourcemaptrue` line, and recompile; but the `pdflatex` call after the `biber` call then fails with:

```
Runaway argument?
{\field {journaltitle}{Proceedings of Some Conference} \field {title}\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \field.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.65 \begin{document}
```

... and one can afterwards confirm that:

```
$ grep abstract test.bbl
      \field{abstract}{% In this paper, we would like to describe the employment of .. %}
      \field{abstract}{% In this paper, we would like to describe the employment of .. %}
```

... with the enabling of the `\DeclareSourcemap`, the `biber.conf` is possibly ignored, and the `abstract` field ends up in the `.bbl` anyway, causing trouble.

So, how can I both use a `\DeclareSourcemap` in my tex file, along with the mapping already set in `biber.conf` (in this case, both have the `abstract` field ignored and unentered in the `.bbl` file - and use the `mycustomfield` as `usera`)?

Comment: That is an interesting problem. It is known that `\DeclareSourcemap` can only be used once (see also [\DeclareSourcemap in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142837/35864)). But I would have thought that Biber's `biber.conf` would still apply regardless. What I find odd is that Biber's documentations states that `biber.conf` takes precedence over `.bcf` while you seem to have experienced the opposite.

Comment: @moewe: While that's true of options and settings more generally, the precedence order is a bit different for `sourcemap` entries (see 3.1.2 of the Biber documentation or 4.5.2 of the BibLaTeX documentation) where `\DeclareSourcemap` takes precedence over the configuration file. Nevertheless, I would've thought that non-conflicting rules wouldn't, you know, conflict...

Comment: @ig0774 Ahhh that explains it, then. As I said two sourcemaps in a document are not possible (I seem to remember reading why some time ago, can't din it now, though), maybe that carries over to the `.conf` file as well.

Answer (score 2):

While I'd still appreciate a more erudite answer on the interference demonstrated in the OP (between `biber.conf` and `\DeclareSourcemap`) in general, I think I managed to fix this particular case.

After stumbling at [biber/biblatex: \DeclareSourcemap conflicting with bcf file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75537/biber-biblatex-declaresourcemap-conflicting-with-bcf-file), and realizing that `biber.conf` actually looks like what is written in `\DeclareSourcemap` - I wrote this, instead, in the OP MWE:

```
\ifDoingSourcemap
  \DeclareSourcemap{
      \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
          \step[fieldsource=mycustomfield]
          \step[fieldset=usera,origfieldval]
      }
        \map[overwrite]{
          \step[fieldsource=abstract]
          \step[fieldset=abstract,null]
      }
    }
  }
  \DeclareFieldFormat{usera}{#1} % not mycustomfield
\fi
```

... and this compiles fine, and basically does what the `biber.conf` used to do (eliminate the `abstract` field from the `.bbl`) - so the `biber.conf` seems not necessary any more (in this case at least).

Comment: Even though this doesn't really explain why the problem arose in the first place. It is definitely the way to go. I really recommend having all of Biber's sourcemapping manipulations in one place, so you don't forget about one and end up with something you didn't want.

Comment: This is correct - the problem is that the `\DeclareSourcemap` and the .conf file write are at the same "level" of maps and the most specific settings (the particular document) take precedence. I could potentially split this as I did with the "style" level of maps but as @moewe says, it will probably encourage real confusing with maps all over the place.

Comment: Actually, this may be a bug, looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug. Please try biber 2.2 dev version now on Sourceforge. biber 2.2 can be used with biblatex 3.0.